# how can I select multiple values from a inner join query with sql?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, inner-join

I would like to make a query to select a number of user emails based on an INNER JOIN.  Presently I can get one value using the following:

```
"SELECT user_email FROM users INNER JOIN users_to_groups ON users.user_id = users_to_groups.user_id WHERE users_to_groups.group_id = ? AND users_to_groups.user_id = ?";
```

What I would like to do is to query the same group_id but with an array of users_to_goups_user_id's to get multiple results in one query.  ie return multiple user emails for user's in a particular group.  Is this possible?

Comment: Please give sample data and expected result

Comment: Sample data is one group_ id and an array of user_id and the result is array of user_email

Comment: Give us 5 rows of data for tables users and users_to_groups. Then what would be the result out of those sample data.

Comment: Yes, use the IN() function to specify your list of `users_to_groups`.`user_id`s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider parameterization with the `IN()` clause after imploding an array of placemakers, `?`. Below assumes using PHP's PDO.

```
$placemarkers = array_fill(0, count($user_id_array), "?");

$strSQL = "SELECT user_email FROM users u" .
          " INNER JOIN users_to_groups g ON u.user_id = g.user_id" .
          " WHERE g.group_id = ?" .
          "   AND g.user_id IN (" . implode(", ", $placemarkers) . ")";

$sth = $conn->prepare($strSQL);

$sth->bindParam(1, $group_id);    
for($i = 0; $i < count($user_id_array); $i++) {
   $sth->bindParam(i+2, $user_id_array[$i], PDO::PARAM_INT); 
}

$sth->execute();
```

Similarly with Python MySQL DB-API cursors:

```
placemarkers = ['%s' for i in user_id_array]
params_list = [group_id] + user_id_array

strSQL = "SELECT user_email FROM users u" + \
         " INNER JOIN users_to_groups g ON u.user_id = g.user_id" + \
         " WHERE g.group_id = %s" + \
         "   AND g.user_id IN ({})".format(", ".join(placemarkers))

cur = conn.cursor()
res = cur.execute(strSQL, params_list)
```